# hadoop datanode listen a random port

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-2.7.2

Hadoop datanode listen a random port(greater than 60000), which is the filename and keyname, can i custom define it?

```
2016-08-19 17:49:27,176 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue

2016-08-19 17:49:27,223 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 64859
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it now, it's defined in yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
    <value>${yarn.nodemanager.hostname}:0</value>
</property>
```